# Spring filter only in dev environemnt

Tags: java, spring, filter

I have a spring boot application and in it a filter defined like that:

```
@Component
public class MyDevFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,
                     FilterChain chain) throws IOException,  ServletException {
.. filter implementation
}
```

I would like this filter to only register in dev environment,
either by spring profile or jvm parameter (doesnt matter which).
How can i achieve that?

Comment: Add `@Profile("your-profile")`. restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put an `@Profile("dev")` annotation on it with the name corresponding to your dev environment (here assuming "dev").

You can then activate it in your `application.properties` file with:

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

Or you can do it at the command-line with:

```
--spring.profiles.active=dev
```

Comment: Can't believe its so simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Annotate your bean with `@Profile("profile-name")` and it will only be created if that profile is active.